# How to find invalid characters?

Tags: text-processing, control-characters

I am trying to filter out record which is having "invalid character"(like control-m `^M` characters or simply not valid characters).

Example:

```
12345 vimal 1235566 ^zfood nation
```

Here, the `^z`, which in Unix vi mode is viewed in blue colour, I need script to check whether the record has invalid or unformatted characters or not.

Comment: Please define your understanding of "invalid character". Because for me `control-m` is perfectly valid

Comment: Please define your "record", preferably through an example.

Comment: 12345 vimal 1235566 ^zfood nation

Comment: here the ^z --> which in unix vi mode is viewed in blue colour, i need script to check whether the record has invalid or unformatted characters or not .. please help me

Comment: Clarifications should go into the question itself, not comments. I have moved your comment into the text of the question.

Comment: Rather famously, Unix *is not a record-oriented operating system*.  So you have to state your file format, including the rules for what is valid, if you are going to start talking about records.

Comment: try something like `perl -pe 's/([^\w\s]+)/#{{$1}}#/g' example` to annotate and define the "invalid chars"...

Comment: Even after the edits, there is no explanation of what the file format is and thus what constitutes character validity.

Answer (score 2):

To remove all lines from a file that have control characters in them:

```
grep -v '[[:cntrl:]]' file >file.modified
```

This will create a new file called `file.modified`.  The `-v` flag to `grep` inverts the sense of the match performed by the utility and `[[:cntrl:]]` will match lines containing control characters.

To remove lines that have non-printable characters in the C locale (for example Unicode characters):

```
LC_ALL=C grep -v '[^[:print:]]' file >file.modified
```

Comment: 000000000102251      HILL HOLIDYA ֠ERWIN PENLAND ֠TRILIA ֠PAYROLL             Direct                          0          AA       1
000000000102251      HILL HOLIDYA ֠ERWIN PENLAND ֠TRILIA ֠PAYROLL             EFT                             0          AB       2
000000000102251      HILL HOLIDYA ֠ERWIN PENLAND ֠TRILIA ֠PAYROLL HILL HOLIDAY/TRILIA - 24 SEMI-MONTHLY       Payroll Deduction       Semi-monthly 15thand           24        AD       3

Comment: Please find the sample "invalid character" which we had recived...see the character "E" in Erwin it looks different in teh similair way "T"rilia and "P"ayroll, i want to find that pattern.. pls let me know how to do it

Comment: @VimalKumar See updated answer.

Comment: it doesnt worked out, can any one pls assist

Comment: @VimalKumar I pasted your text into a new file called `/tmp/test` and ran a variation of what @Kusalananda suggested `$ LC_ALL=C grep '[^[:print:]]' /tmp/test`. This printed out your text with the invalid characters highlighted. Sounds like this is what you want.